# How to find a substring between two \n using regex?

Tags: java, regex

I need to locate a person's name in the following string:

```
 TI35635: 71-3463463409 wa36ued i56tle Ro356 IL
    Involved Subject
     Name: PETER SMITH
     Address: 1 MAIN AVE
```

**So, the rule I should follow is the following: the substring is whatevet goes right after "Subject \n+ Name:" and before "hits \n" I must follow this rule, because some words in the original String (too long) that I did not post could not be unique**

I tried the following:

```
Pattern patternName = Pattern.compile("(?:Subject.?)(\\n)(Name:.*?)\\n", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher matcherName = patternName.matcher(text);
matcherName.find();
```

Please help me correct it

Comment: You seem to have a bunch of white space before `Name:` which you are not accounting for.

Comment: Ummm... Before `"hits \n"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just skip the whitespace before attempting to match the group containing the name. You can use `\s` which will not only match spaces but also newline characters

```
Pattern patternName = 
           Pattern.compile("(?:Subject.?)\\s+(Name:.*?)\\n", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Group `1` contains:

```
Name: PETER SMITH
```

Read the [Pattern javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for a full list of characters matched by `\s`

Comment: It works PERFERCT!!! However, i got a little question, why `group() and group(0)` give the same result that includes the word `Subject`, but `group(1)` does not include this word?

Comment: `group()` and `group(0)` are basically the same - they return the complete matched `String`. `group(1)` returns the first `String` to appear in a capturing group. Your first group is a non-capturing group so doesnt appear in group `1`

Answer (score 1):

Your example has 3 groups a.e `O(n^3)` where n is char number.

Generally regex is good if we want to replace multiple times.

In your case regex is too expensive. (from my view). Iwould use followed example:

```
String str = "TI35635: 71-3463463409 wa36ued i56tle Ro356 IL\r\n" + 
                "    Involved Subject\r\n" + 
                "     Name: PETER SMITH\r\n" + 
                "     Address: 1 MAIN AVE";

    StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder();

    for(String line : str.split(System.getProperty("line.separator"))){
        if(line.contains("Name: ")){
            String temp = line.split(": ")[0];
            temp = temp + ": " + "New Name"; 
            buff.append(temp).append("\n");
        }
        else{
            buff.append(line).append("\n");
        }           
    }       

    System.out.println(buff.toString());
```

Output:

```
TI35635: 71-3463463409 wa36ued i56tle Ro356 IL
    Involved Subject
     Name: New Name
     Address: 1 MAIN AVE
```

Comment: The problem with using String split and append operations is that they require you to create all-new Strings, which can be cumbersome in large programs.

Comment: In what way is regex expensive here?  Can you clarify?

Comment: regex is expensive. If i want to replace all text into tags for HTML/XML I would use regex. To replace one word in one line - manual way

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I cannot use `indexOf("Name: ")` because the word Name is not unique in the original String (i did not post all string). I must follow the rule: `"Subject+\n+Name:"`

Comment: @AndreiVasilev see my edit, i didn't use indexOf. Actually your example has 3 groups a.e O(n^3) where n is char number.

Answer (score 1):

You could represent the Regex for the name as:

```
([ \\t\\x0B\\f\\r]*[a-zA-Z]+)*
```

This represents a sequence of zero or more of the following: zero or more spaces (non-newlines), followed by one or more letters.  Should handle the names within your larger Regex.

Alternatively, \s represents whitespace (although it includes newlines) and \w represents any letter or number character.

Comment: Sorry, my earlier comment misunderstood what you were trying to achieve; which is why I posted a different one.  So you want white space but no newlines, and letters but not numbers or punctuation?  OK, fair enough.

Comment: Is this equivalent to `[ \t\x0B\f\ra-zA-Z]*` or is there a difference that I don't understand?

Comment: The difference is that in mine, if there are spaces there must be at least one letter for the regex to match.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Yours can't end with trailing whitespace.  I understand now.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the regular expression:

```
Subject[ ]*\r?\n[ ]*(Name:.*)
```

e.g.:

```
private static final Pattern REGEX_PATTERN = 
        Pattern.compile("Subject[ ]*\\r?\\n[ ]*(Name:.*)");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "TI35635: 71-3463463409 wa36ued i56tle Ro356 IL\n    Involved Subject\n     Name: PETER SMITH\n     Address: 1 MAIN AVE";

    Matcher matcher = REGEX_PATTERN.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find(1)) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Name: PETER SMITH
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in just one line:

```
String name = str.replaceAll("(?sm).*Subject\\s+Name:(.*?)?$.*", "$1");
```

If the name is not found, the result will be blank.

I've also made it so it will work on windows files too.

---

Here's some test code:

```
String str = " TI35635: 71-3463463409 wa36ued i56tle Ro356 IL\n    Involved Subject\n     Name: PETER SMITH\n     Address: 1 MAIN AVE";
String name = str.replaceAll("(?sm).*Subject\s+Name:(.*?)?$.*", "$1");
System.out.println("Name = " + name);;
```

Output:

```
Name = PETER SMITH
```